# The form cannot be loaded. Because the session state is not activated

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007

I am using infopath 2007 forms in sharepoint 2007. When i want to open the forms in browser stored in the form libraries, it is saying a message that:
"The form cannot be loaded. Because the session state is not activated."

How can i solve this issue..... thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In your sharepoint site web config
uncommet this line in httpModules

```
<!-- <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/> -->
```